# Is there a Sleep/Pause/Wait function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, sleep

Is there a JavaScript function that simulates the operation of the `sleep` function in PHP — a function that pauses code execution for x milliseconds, and then resumes where it left off?

I found some things here on Stack Overflow, but nothing useful.

Answer (score 193, accepted):

You need to re-factor the code into pieces. This doesn't stop execution, it just puts a delay in between the parts.

```
function partA() {
  ...
  window.setTimeout(partB,1000);
}

function partB() {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Can you pass a parameter to `partB` at `window.setTimeout(partB,1000)`?

Comment: If you wrap it in an anonymous function, such as in Michael Haren's answer, then you can.

Comment: This answer is only half correct.  `setTimeout()` is not the same as `sleep()`.  `setTimeout()` schedules the named function to be executed asynchronously at a set time in the future.  The rest of your code will not wait until the `partB` function has executed, which is not the same functionality as `sleep()`.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4122268/using-settimeout-synchronously-in-javascript

Comment: This also answers the age-old question of "What comes before Part-B?"

Answer (score 122):

You can't (and shouldn't) block processing with a sleep function. However, you can use `setTimeout` to kick off a function after a delay:

```
setTimeout(function(){alert("hi")}, 1000);
```

Depending on your needs, `setInterval` might be useful, too.

Comment: `sleep` doesn't block processing; it allows processing to continue.

Comment: Anonymous functions are not recommend as a security risk according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout

Comment: @Bananenaffe- if I'm reading the right warning on that docs page, the concern isn't around anonymous functions, it's with code passed as a `string`, which must be executed via `eval`.

Answer (score 13):

setTimeout() function it's use to delay a process in JavaScript.

[w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp) has an easy tutorial about this function.

Comment: w3School is not reliable, use this instead: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout