# Prompting a value with setTimeout function

Tags: javascript

```
var label = prompt('Label for Vertical Line');
```

This code returns the value in `label` which I enter in the prompted field. But I want some time delay to get the prompted value.

I'm using this code:

```
var label=alertWithoutNotice();
function alertWithoutNotice(){
    var lab;
    setTimeout(function(){
        lab=prompt('Label for Vertical Line');
    }, 1200);
    return lab;
}
```

But this doesn't return any value. Please tell me what is wrong?

Comment: the function is executed by setTimeout after lab has been returned

Comment: so what should I do?can you give me the proper code?

Comment: you need to chain the behavior that uses lab into the end of the function given to setTimeout

Answer (score 0):

This is a chronological issue. `setTimeout` schedules an **asynchronous** event. That means, until it runs, the rest of your script will continue to execute.

The result is your `return lab` line is executed before the timeout callback fires. And so on the return, `lab` is undefined at that point.

As such, you can't return values from asynchronous events, or at least not meaningfully.

Something like jQuery's deferred objects would be your best route to a fix here, but I don't know if jQuery is an option for you.

Comment: how can I get the prompted value using setTimeout function??

Comment: Well you already ARE getting it; it's just you can't return from it, for the reasons I said. There is no easy fix with the pattern you currently have; your script will continue to run but without a value for `lab`, because it doesn't have one until the callback fires.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are returning value before get inside timeout because setTimeout function is asynchronous.

Take a look here to use synchronously: [using setTimeout synchronously in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4122268/using-settimeout-synchronously-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are dialing with asynchronous operation the simplest approach here is to use a callback function. For example:

```
alertWithoutNotice(function(label) {
    alert(label)
});

function alertWithoutNotice(callback) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        callback(prompt('Label for Vertical Line'));
    }, 1200);
}
```

So think of it is that `alertWithoutNotice` is notified when `label` is available. When it happens callback is invoked.

Comment: ok got it...but how do I store the `label` value in a variable?

Comment: You need to change your approach completely. It doesn't make sense to store it in variable if you have async code. Use callbacks.