# Javascript code not running sequentially

Tags: javascript

Halcyon helped with the loop here - but is there any way to stop the subsequent code from running, until after the loop has finished:

When I run the code below, I get the prompt for entering my name, before the scrollDown function runs - but the input prompt as AFTER the scrollDown code:

```js
function scrollDown(num_times) {
  num_times -= 1;
  if (num_times === 0) {
    return;
  }
  window.scrollBy(0, 500); // horizontal and vertical scroll increments
  setTimeout(function() {
    scrollDown(num_times);
  }, 500);
}
//This should run first and scroll the screen before prompting
scrollDown(30); // scroll down 30 times


//However this prompt comes up before the above code has ran
var kw = prompt("Please enter your name");
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks, Mark

Comment: @FailedUnitTest: No, code in JavaScript runs **synchronously** unless otherwise stated. Promise callbacks and `setTimeout` callbacks are both the kinds of "otherwise stated" things.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I was thinking of ajax calls for some reason.

Comment: You will probably need to use flags around your prompt, similar to in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4122268/using-settimeout-synchronously-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var kw;

function scrollDown(num_times) {
  if (num_times === 0) {
    /* you can define your prompt after scrollDown has ended */
    kw = prompt("Please enter your name");
    return;
  }
  window.scrollBy(0, 500);
  setTimeout(function() {
    scrollDown(num_times - 1);
  }, 500);
}

scrollDown(30);
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the code in a callback that you run after the last scroll iteration.

```js
function scrollDown(num_times, callback) {
  if (num_times === 0) {
    callback();
  }
  window.scrollBy(0, 500); // horizontal and vertical scroll increments
  setTimeout(function() {
    scrollDown(num_times - 1, callback);
  }, 500);
}
//This should run first and scroll the screen before prompting
scrollDown(30, function() {
    kw = prompt("Please enter your name");
    document.getElementById("result").textContent = kw;
}
); // scroll down 30 times
```

```html
Your name is: <span id="result"></span>
```