# synchronous while loop javascript

Tags: javascript, while-loop, callback, synchronous

i want this output 1,1,1,....

instead of 2,1

i want to run synchronously

```js
//just wait 2 seconds
function s(callback){
    setTimeout(() => {
        callback()
    }, 2000);
}
a=[2]
while (a.length!==0){
    a.shift()
    s(()=>{
        a.push(2)
        console.log('1');
    })
}
console.log('2');
```

Comment: This is running synchronously. `setTimeout` doesnot mean code is running asynchronously

Comment: This problem might be already resolved there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4122268/using-settimeout-synchronously-in-javascript

Comment: Do you want an infinite loop printing 1?

Comment: It is unclear why the array even exists here `a=[2]`, it would be interesting to know the reason for that -although not part of the problem it seems.

Comment: As a infinite loop this may eventually pop an error in modern browsers that detect that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way you can achieve this, using your current code, is using `async/await` and Promises.

```js
//just wait 2 seconds
function s(callback) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      callback()
      resolve()
    }, 2000);
  })
}

const main = async function() {
  const a = [2];
  while (a.length !== 0) {
    a.shift()
    // This "waits" for s to complete. And s returns a Promise which completes after 2 secs
    await s(() => {
      a.push(2)
      console.log('1');
    })
  }
  console.log('2');
}

main()
```

If you really just need an infinite loop `while(true) { /* ... */ }` is enough.