# setTimeout isn't working properly in the while loop

Tags: javascript

I need it to pause for 3 seconds at the end of every loop, but it's not pausing. How do I fix this? Example codes would be appreciated.

```js
function file_get_contents(url, callback) {
  fetch(url).then(res => res.text()).then(text => callback(text));
}

function theCallBack(text) {
  text = text.replace(/google/g, "")
  let matches = text.match(/www.[a-z\-]+?.com/g);
  console.log(matches[0]);
};

var theArray = ["https://www.google.com/search?q=one", "https://www.google.com/search?q=two", "https://www.google.com/search?q=three"];
var count = theArray.length;

while (count > 0) {
  console.log(count);
  count--;
  file_get_contents(theArray[count], theCallBack);
  setTimeout(function() {}, 3000);
}
```

Comment: What do you need to pause?

Comment: `while` loops do not wait for `setTimeout`s

Comment: `3 seconds at the end of every loop`, Do you mean `3 seconds at the end of every successful fetch()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `Promise` to pause the program and `await` it.

```js
const wait = (ms) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));


function file_get_contents(url, callback) {
  fetch(url).then(res => res.text()).then(text => callback(text));
}

function theCallBack(text) {
  text = text.replace(/google/g, "")
  let matches = text.match(/www.[a-z\-]+?.com/g);
  console.log(matches[0]);
};

var theArray = ["https://www.google.com/search?q=one", "https://www.google.com/search?q=two", "https://www.google.com/search?q=three"];
var count = theArray.length;



(async() => {
  for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    console.log(i + 1);
    file_get_contents(theArray[i], theCallBack);
    await wait(3000);
  }
})();
```

Comment: There's a fail to load resource error. If you run code snippet it will also only show 1, 2, 3.

Comment: I found the error, need to replace theArray[count] with theArray[i]

Comment: lol thx for pointing out. Fixed now!

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is setTineout() async function, so you need make it sync, to work as you want.

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Timeouts_and_intervals

https://stackoverflow.com/a/50357618